# Flask-WTF generate token manually in routes

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

So i was trying to create backend server with flask. After some reading on https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/csrf/, the way to create csrf token with Flask-WTF was to put `form.csrf_token` in the response, something like this

```
<form method="post">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
</form>
```

However, my backend server does not send the data directly to the client, it first send the data to frontend server, where the frontend server will be the one that send the data to the client. My route function looks like this

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    response_data = {
    "status":"ok"
    }
    # ...
    # add code here
    # ...
    return make_response(jsonify(response_data)),HTTPStatus.OK.value
```

My idea was first to create csrf token to be stored in cookie, then use the csrf token in the cookie to generate another csrf token which will be used in the form.

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    response_data = {
    "status":"ok"
    }
    # ...
    # add code here
    # ...
    csrf_token_cookie = generate_csrf_token()
    form_csrf_token = generate_csrf_token(csrf_token_cookie)
    response_data['form_csrf_token'] = form_csrf_token
    response = make_response(jsonify(response_data))
    resp.set_cookie('csrf_token_cookie', csrf_token_cookie)
    return response,HTTPStatus.OK.value
```

The function `generate_csrf_token()` does not exist and is just how i imaged my code is going to be. The backend server will pass the `csrf_token_cookie` cookie to frontend server, which then pass the cookie to the client. When the client submit the form, the csrf token in the cookie will be matched with the csrf token in the form.

I tried to find the function in Flask-WTF to achieve what i need, but so far i have not found it. How do i do this using Flask-WTF ?

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering, i found the function to generate csrf token. More information at https://github.com/wtforms/flask-wtf/blob/main/src/flask_wtf/csrf.py.

First make sure the app is protected by Flask-WTF

```
app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

Then set the secret key used by Flask-WTF to generate csrf token

```
app['SECRET_KEY'] = "Your secret key here"
```

then you can generate csrf token with the `generate_csrf()` function

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import generate_csrf
csrf_token = generate_csrf(token_key="your key here")
```

It turns out that when flask app is protected by Flask-WTF, session cookie is automatically generated and set by Flask-WTF to tie the csrf token to the user session, so there is no need to manually create session cookie.

[image]